# Как прописать функцию для декоратора в отдельном файле?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
dp.callback_query_handler(process_callback_button1, lambda c: c.data == 'button_1')
```

Comment: А проблема в чем? Пропишите ее в отдельном файле, потом импортируйте ее в этом.

Answer (score 0):

Можете написать анонимную или обычную функцию в отдельном .py файле, затем импортировать её через `import` в свой основной файл.